# Creating a WorkBadge in a community via apex

Tags: apex, community, work.com

I've got a batch class that goes through and assigns people badges based on the amount of time that they've been a user. However, these badges only show up in the internal Salesforce portal, and not in their community (as is desired). I did a little research and discovered this link

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_networks_badges.htm

"Portal and communities users can see the badges they give and receive in a community only in that community"

So my question is, is there anyway to assign these badges to a specific community via apex? I couldn't find any examples. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Actually i can probably assign it with the NetworkID on the WorkBadge